# Esquema de bases de datos relacionales mysql

Tags: mysql

Recién estoy aprendiendo bases de datos relacionales mysql, y  tratando de armar el esquema de bases de datos para una aplicación web tengo que un usuario, que se registra mediante un form, escoge la ciudad y la sede, entonces entre users y city debería tener una relación uno a uno creo yo, también el usuario debe elegir una sola ubicación dentro de la ciudad también seria uno a uno ?

Pero tengo una confusión grande porque las tablas city y location las llena el admin entonces no si entre esas dos se establece una relación muchos a muchos, además como relacionaría el usuario después, para realizar las búsquedas por usuario, ciudad y/o ubicación.

La aplicación registra usuarios para un gimnasio, por lo que el usuario solo se puede registrar en una ciudad(tabla city) y en una cede (tabla location), las ciudades tienen multiples cedes.
el usuario solo puede acceder a la ciudad y cede donde se registró
El admin podrá realizar búsquedas por usuario, ciudad y/o ubicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    names varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastNames varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rol varchar(50) NOT NULL
);



CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    cityName varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);



CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    locationName varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES city(city_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No puedes poner la columna `user_id` en `city`, una ciudad no pertenece a un usuario en exclusivo. Tendrías que crear una tabla **`user_location`**  con las columnas `user_id` y `location_id` para expresar la relación que pretendes.

Comment: que es location? que es city? Tene en cuenta que esta pregunta, ademas de que puede no tener una respuesta unica, implica suponer que tiene cada campo. Para eso, necesitariamos ver el diccionario de datos para entender que tiene cada campo. Tambien, las reglas de negocios. Una persona puede tener mas de una ciudad? solo tiene una? una ciudad puede estar en mas de una location? que es la sede? lo que llamas location? nosotros no sabemos tus reglas de negocios, y para dar una respuesta al menos logica, se necesita saberlas...

Comment: Hola si tiene razón acabo de editar la pregunta para agregar mas información.

Comment: Hola , no solamente puede acceder a la ciudad y cede donde se registró

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo entiendo más o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cityName varchar(31) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    locationName varchar(31) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES city(city_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    names varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastNames varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rol varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    location_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES location(location_id)
);
```

La idea es que los usuarios están en una localización y las localizaciones están en una determinada ciudad

Comment: seria ideal preguntar que es locations, ya que no le veo ningun sentido de existir... antes de contestar estas preguntas, que quien pregunta haga un diccionario de datos seria ideal para poder explicarle bien... no?

Comment: Hola son las cedes

Answer (score 1):

No puedes poner la columna `user_id` en `city`, **una ciudad no pertenece a un usuario en exclusivo**. Y tendrías que duplicar ciudades en esa misma tabla para expresar las relaciones.

Imaginemos que con este diseño:

```
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    cityName varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Haya dos usuarios con la misma ciudad, tendrías redundancia de datos en `cityName`, lo cual es inviable:

```
city_id   cityName   user_id
------------------------------
   1        París       1
   99       París       1896
```

Además de eso, en `city` tendría que haber tantas filas como usuarios, con un montón de redundancias, **todo por el simple hecho de haber metido `user_id` dentro de la tabla `city`**.

Dos soluciones son posibles:

1. Si un `user` tendrá una sola `location` lo propio sería trasladar la columna `id_location` a la tabla `user` como llave foránea.

Las tablas serían creadas **en el siguiente orden**, teniendo en cuenta que las tablas cuyas columnas son llaves foráneas en otras tablas tienen que ser creadas antes, de lo contrario el `CREATE TABLE` no encontrará la tabla de referencia y el código fallará.

```
-- 1º la tabla city, sin user_id, por lo ya explicado
-- y se crea primero porque será referenciada en location con FK
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cityName varchar(150) NOT NULL    
);

-- 2º la tabla location
-- y se crea antes de users porque allí su columna location_id 
-- será referenciada como FK
CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    locationName varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES city(city_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    names varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastNames varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rol varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    location_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES location(location_id)
);
```

2. Si un `user` puede tener más de una `location` tendrías que crear  una tabla `user_location` para expresar la relación. En este caso convendría agregar una restricción `UNIQUE` que incluya a `usar_id` y a `location_id`, para impedir que el mismo usuario tengas más de una vez la misma location.

El orden de creación de tablas sería así:

```
-- 1º la tabla city, sin user_id, por lo ya explicado
-- y se crea primero porque será referenciada en location con FK
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cityName varchar(150) NOT NULL    
);

-- 2º la tabla location
-- y se crea antes de users porque allí su columna location_id 
-- será referenciada como FK
CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    city_id int NOT NULL,
    locationName varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES city(city_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

-- En este caso users no tiene columna location_id
-- la relación se expresa en la tabla user_location
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    names varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastNames varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rol varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_location (
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    location_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_location_1 FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_location_2 FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES location(location_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT uc_user_location UNIQUE (user_id , location_id)
);
```

En este caso la columna `location_id` sería sacada de la tabla `user`.

En cualquiera de los casos, accederías a la ciudad por medio de la columna `city_id` de la tabla `location`.

Ten en cuenta que en un contexto más amplio la misma tabla `city` (o `location`) puede participar de otras relaciones con respecto a `user`, por ejemplo, si se necesitara saber la ciudad donde reside, o la ciudad donde trabaja, o la ciudad donde nació. Por ese motivo tablas como `city` no deben jamás tener columnas extrañas. Deben permanecer como una entidad única dentro de tu modelo de datos. Y, en un contexto de internacionalización, `city` tendría que incorporar una columna `id_country`  (o un id de departamento o de provincia), porque una ciudad puede llamarse igual en dos países distintos.

**PD:**

Evita confusiones en la convención de nombre. Lo habitual es definir los nombres de tablas en singular. Lo digo porque has definido `users`. Mientras que `city` y `location` están es singular. No ayuda tener disparidad en la conveción de nombre en tus tablas.

Comment: Entiendo, pero me genera un problema en la tabla users #1005 - No puedo crear tabla `nopainnogain`.`users` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: `users` debería crearse después de `location`.

Comment: Como bien indica @Sal, en estos casos el orden de creación de tablas es determinante. Deben crearse primero las tablas con alguna referencia en otras tablas, si se hace al revés dará error al no estar aún creada la tabla cuando se intenta hacer referencia a ella. Aparte de eso había otros pequeños errores que han sido corregidos (como alguna columna `varchar` cuyo tamaño no se indicaba).